# Set default content_type for Flask test client

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

Is there a way to set the default `content_type` value for the test client in Flask?

For example, if I have the following test:

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        from my_flask_project import app
        self.client = app.test_client()

    def test_request_one(self):
        self.client.post(
            data='{}'
            content_type='application/json'
        )

    def test_request_two(self):
        self.client.post(
            data='{}'
            content_type='application/json'
        )
```

All of my test cases are going to set `content_type='application/json'`. I would like to set `application/json` as the default content type for requests but I couldn't find any documentation on how to do this.

Something like this would be ideal:

```
def setUp(self):
    from my_flask_project import app
    self.client = app.test_client(
        default_content_type='application/json'
    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For *most* headers, you can pass an [`environ_base`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/latest/test/#werkzeug.test.EnvironBuilder) dict to set other headers. However, the test client will [always set the `Content-Type` header](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/0644c6263b1b3b6705426782c1b39a15e04450af/werkzeug/test.py#L572-L590) to the value passed in, overriding the base. There's also `environ_overrides`, which can override that override, but that means you can't set the header to anything else, which is probably not what you want.

Create a custom [`TestClient`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.testing.FlaskClient) class that sets a default content type if one is not passed. Assign that class to your Flask app [`test_client_class`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Flask.test_client_class) and it will use it when creating test clients.

```
from flask.testing import FlaskClient

class CustomClient(FlaskClient):
    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('content_type', 'application/json')
        return super().open(*args, **kwargs)

app.test_client_class = CustomClient
```

You can use this technique for any arg, not just `content_type`, including `environ_base`.

Answer (score 4):

I found a simpler solution is to use the `Client` parameter `json` instead of `data`. This way it is explicit what data you are sending but don't need to set/override the header.

From the Flask [docs](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/test/#request-body):

> A shortcut when testing JSON APIs is to pass a dict to json instead of using data. This will automatically call json.dumps() and set the content type to application/json. Additionally, if the app returns JSON, response.json will automatically call json.loads().

```
response = client.post("/api", json={"a": "value", "b": 1})
obj = response.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @davidism's answer, there is a particular case with the `Authorization` header: use the following form:

```
class CustomClient(FlaskClient):
    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('headers', {'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'})
        return super().open(*args, **kwargs)
```